# Ubuntu 13.10 + Gnome 3.10, some menu's lack left padding

Tags: gnome, themes

I just installed Gnome 3.10 (I know - it's experimental) and everything is working great except for some menu's seem to lack any left padding, causing the text to kind of stick to the edge.

[image]

Anyone know of a solution to this issue? I am using Zukwito from the webupd8 repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the instructions from webupd8 are incomplete and I was still on gnome 3.8. I tried again using the instructions given here: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html

This resolved my issue.

Comment: Note the original Zukitwo is available [here](http://lassekongo83.deviantart.com/art/Zukitwo-203936861) - works nicely apart from odd bits around the edges...